# Why exec-path doesn't contain /usr/local/bin while /etc/paths already contains it?

Tags: osx, exec-path

Emacs 24.5.1 on OS X 10.11.1.

This is the content of `/etc/paths`:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

This is the value of `exec-path`:

```
("/usr/bin"
 "/bin"
 "/usr/sbin"
 "/sbin" "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin-x86_64-10_9" 
 "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/libexec-x86_64-10_9" 
 "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/libexec" 
 "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin")
```

Why doesn't it contain `/usr/local/bin`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OS X only evaluates `/etc/paths` and `/etc/paths.d/` for shell sessions, through an invocation of `path_helper` in the global shell profile.

GUI applications have a different launch path (through launchd as far as I know), which includes a different environment and a different environment configuration.  Specifically, GUI applications do not inherit `$PATH` from a shell session, and thus do not get `$PATH` entries from the aforementioned files.

You can work around this behaviour with [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell), which sets `exec-path` based on the `$PATH` value of a shell session.  This package is more or less a standard equipment for Emacs users on OS X.

Comment: My memory is wrong. I know `$PATH` is only for shell but thought `etc/paths` is for all.

Answer (score 1):

For future searchers: I used this to solve the problem:

https://github.com/arouanet/path-helper

It is a small elisp module that mimics the behavior of the `/usr/libexec/path_helper` 
utility available on MacOS.

I added these lines to my .emacs

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; set path correctly on MacOS, based on /etc/paths
(if (memq window-system '(ns mac))
  (path-helper-setenv "PATH"))
```

For more information you may want to examine [this link on emacswiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsApp).

Answer (score -1):

> Emacs initializes ‘exec-path’ when it starts up, based on the value of the environment variable ‘PATH’.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Subprocess Creation` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: I think the OP's question is rather, why the contents of this file do not end up in `$PATH` for an Emacs session, like they do for a shell session.

Comment: No doubt you're right. This answer would at least have enabled them to realise what the *real* question actually was, though. I would suggest to whoever cast the down-vote that voting down an answer which *does* answer the stated question is perhaps a little bit harsh.

Comment: I cast the down vote because I think that this does not answer the question at all.  It's entirely unrelated to the actual issue.  Besides, in my opinion just quoting the manual with no context is not a proper answer.

Comment: They appeared to be confused about where the contents of `exec-path` came from, and believed that their `/etc/paths` file had something to do with it. I quoted the manual to show that this file has nothing to do with `exec-path` (and they would have then been able to easily confirm that Emacs does indeed use the value of `PATH`). I'm unsure as to what additional context I could have usefully provided. (I could have stated explicitly that the quote therefore meant that the value did not come from `/etc/paths`, but that would have seemed a bit redundant.)